# JavaFX how to style the button part of a checkbox?

Tags: css, checkbox, javafx, styling

I am trying to do some css styling in a stylesheet for a JavaFX scene.
It is going to be loaded upon opening the scene, and targets all the "basic" elements of a scene.

My problem is that i can't seem to find the right combination of code, to change the background color, of the button in a standard JavaFX checkbox.

This is where i am now:

```
.check-box:selected{
    -fx-background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

I have tried some variants of the above, like

```
.check-box .button{
    -fx-fill: #00FF00;
    -fx-background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

and others, but without success.

So in general, how do i access a button in a checkbox?

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parts of the `CheckBox` to apply the `-fx-background-color` to are `.box` and `.box > .mark` in case you want to change the mark color:

```css
.check-box:selected > .box {
    /* background color for selected checkbox */
    -fx-background-color: lime;
}

.check-box > .box {
    /* background color of unselected checkbox */
    -fx-background-color: red;
}

.check-box:selected > .box > .mark,
.check-box:indeterminate  > .box > .mark {
    /* modify mark color */
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Perfect - Thank you :-)